# Swift Loop through [String: Any] and get difference to Struct or Class properties

Tags: swift

I have a struct with several properties. How can I write a function that takes a dictionary of type [String: Any] and creates another dictionary of type [String: Any] that contains only keys and values where the input dictionary's value was different from the struct property value with the same name?

A struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
   var a: Bool = false
   var b: String = "random"
   var c: Int = 2
}
```

Desired function call:

```
let myStruct = MyStruct()
let input: [String: Any] = ["b": "test", "c": 2]
let result: [String: Any] = myStruct.getDiff(input)
```

Desired result for the example input:

```
result = ["b": "test"]
```

Besides a struct, how would this be done for comparing the [String: Any] to a class?

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing? In most cases, when you are trying to iterate through all properties of a type, you are doing something wrong and should reconsider what is the actual problem you are trying to solve and why would you choose this particular solution.

Comment: I have a class that represents a model stored as a Firebase Firestore document. I'd like to send a single update to the database with the changed values. This requires a dictionary to be sent. I just realized that I'm already creating a dictionary of model properties, I suppose it would be better to compare the two dictionaries.

Comment: The challenge with that last solution is that I'd need to compare two value types of type `Any`

Comment: Don't compare the dictionaries, since they're not strongly typed. As for converting your model into a dictionary, `JSONSerialization` can handle that for you. Or if you just need the JSON String, `JSONEncoder` and making your class `Encodable` also works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The specific syntax you've provided is probably not possible. Packing things into a `[String: Any]` likely loses too much information to be recovered. But your overall goal is certainly possible.

The important piece is `input`. Rather than `[String: Any]`, we're going to use an explicit type, ValueChange:

```
let input = [
    ValueChange(key: "b", changedTo: "test"),
    ValueChange(key: "c", changedTo: 2),
]
```

Creating a new type like this allows us to capture all the types, and enforce certain rules, particularly that the values are `Equatable`:

```
struct ValueChange {
    init<Value: Equatable>(key: String, changedTo newValue: Value) {...}
}
```

I'll come back to ValueChange in a moment, but first I want to go back to how it'll be used. Since you want a `.getDiff(...)` syntax, it'll be best to create an extension using a protocol:

```
protocol DictionaryDiffComputing {}

extension DictionaryDiffComputing {
    func getDiff(_ changes: [ValueChange]) -> [String: Any] {
        Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            changes.compactMap { $0.changedValue(self) })
    }
}
```

The protocol has no requirements. It just exists to say "these types have the `getDiff` method." This method needs ValueChange to provide us a `(String, Any)` tuple if the value has changed.

This is where the problem gets interesting, I'll just show the answer and then discuss it.

```
struct ValueChange {
    let changedValue: (_ object: Any) -> (String, Any)? // (key, newValue)

    init<Value: Equatable>(key: String, changedTo newValue: Value) {
        self.changedValue = { object in

            // Get the old value as an Any using Mirror
            guard let oldAnyValue: Any = Mirror(reflecting: object)
                .children
                .first(where: { $0.label == key })?
                .value
                else {
                    assertionFailure("Unknown key: \(key)")
                    return nil
            }

            // Make sure it's the correct type
            guard let oldValue = oldAnyValue as? Value else {
                assertionFailure("Bad type for values (\(oldAnyValue)). Expected: \(Value.self)")
                return nil
            }

            // Compare the values
            return newValue != oldValue ? (key, newValue) : nil
        }
    }
}
```

This uses Mirror to pull out the old value to compare as an Any type, then it converts it to the correct Value type. This is the power of the generic `init`. Since we know the type a compile time, we can capture it inside this closure, erasing that type from the outside world, but being able to work with it at runtime.

```
extension MyStruct: DictionaryDiffComputing {}
let myStruct = MyStruct()
myStruct.getDiff(input) // ["b": "test"]
```

What I really don't like about this answer is that it's very unsafe. Note the two calls to `assertionFailure`. There is nothing about ValueChange that ensures that the key exists or that the value is the correct type. If you change the name or type a property, your program will either crash or behave incorrectly, and there's nothing the compiler can do to help you.

You can make this a lot more type-safe and the code much simpler at the cost of a slightly more verbose calling syntax:

```
protocol DictionaryDiffComputing {}

struct ValueChange<Root> {
    let changedValue: (_ object: Root) -> (String, Any)? // (key, newValue)

    init<Value: Equatable>(key: String, keyPath: KeyPath<Root, Value>, changedTo newValue: Value) {
        self.changedValue = { newValue != $0[keyPath: keyPath] ? (key, newValue) : nil }
    }
}

extension DictionaryDiffComputing {
    func getDiff(_ changes: [ValueChange<Self>]) -> [String: Any] {
        Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            changes.compactMap { $0.changedValue(self) })
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct()

let input: [ValueChange<MyStruct>] = [
    ValueChange(key: "b", keyPath: \.b, changedTo: "test"),
    ValueChange(key: "c", keyPath: \.c, changedTo: 2),
]

myStruct.getDiff(input)
```

If you use this approach, you know that the property exists on this type, and that the value is the correct type for that property. You also get some extra power, since you can use any key path you like starting at this root type. That means you can do things like:

```
ValueChange(key: "b_length", keyPath: \.b.count, changedTo: 4),
```

You could cleanup the requirement for `key` in `ValueChange` by adding some mapping dictionary of key path to key name (a `static var` protocol requirement for example), but I don't know of a way to generate this automatically, and I don't know any good way to convert a key path into an appropriate string.